# Draw only part of data in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I looking for a way to only draw part of the data set in area chart. There is a slider above the chart that can limit the range of one series in the chart while other stile rendered in whole. I wonder whats the best way to do this. The only idea at the moment is to redraw the chart every time the slider moves but I'm afraid this could result in worse performance. Maybe this could be done with something like mask on the SVG element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came up with a simple solution by just clipping the svg graph with an clip path:

```
    //var chart is the actual HighChartsInstance;
    var renderer = chart.renderer;
    var group = renderer.g().add();
    var clipPath = renderer.createElement("clipPath");

    clipPath.element.id = 'clip';
    var rect = renderer.rect(0, 0, 200, 400).add(clipPath);
    this.clippingMask = rect.element; //reference to the clipping rect which width is changed by the slider

    clipPath.add(group);
    chart.series[1].group.element.setAttribute('clip-path', "url(#clip)");
    chart.series[1].group.element.childNodes[0].setAttribute('clip-path', "url(#clip)");
```

Comment: Great solution! Exactly what I was looking for. 

Is there some other way to get the reference to the rect instead of:
    this.clippingMask = rect.element;
?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few ways

- use highstock which contains "slider" http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/
- use highstock.js and highcharts chart with scroller http://jsfiddle.net/UCmUx/

  ```
  scrollbar:{
          enabled:true
      },
  ```
- use highcharts chart without scroller http://jsfiddle.net/UCmUx/1/ and in case when you move your own scroller, then use setExtremes() http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes()

Comment: Seems my question was not clear enough. Im looking for a way where the use can cut of parts from a series, while others series are displayed in whole. Its should visualize the slider setting to the user.

Comment: Other way is i.e during slide use setData() or addPoint() functions

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData()
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.addPoint()

Answer (score 0):

I think one option is to modify the series data which you want to restrict, and then call:

```
 chart.series[n].setData(newData);
```

where 'n' is the number of the series you are truncating. newData is a copy of the series data with the unwanted points taken out. You will need to specify x and y values in the series in order for it to be plotted in the correct position.